# transfer unstaged changes of one branch into another

Tags: git

In my application I am working on a branch called `v4.0`.

In that branch I have done changes in 13-14 files that are unstaged and after some time I realized that I had to do this on `v4.0.1`, this happened by mistake. The changes on v4.0 are unstaged.

Is there any way that to transfer all the changes in `v4.0.1` that I have created from `v4.0` without staging that changes in `v4.0`.

Comment: Just to confirm, you know the difference between staging and committing?

Comment: @iBug yes. Committing is to adding the changes into the branch and staging is a step before we do the commit. Its just like a phase where either we can remove the changes or to add the changes for commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you know that staging is different from committing, you can try extracting the diff and apply them later:

First, extract the diff (make sure the diff file is outside your repository, or ignored in `.gitignore`):

```
git diff > ../unstaged.diff
```

Then, drop the unstaged changes:

```
git stash save --keep-index --include-untracked
```

Checkout the target branch and apply the diff:

```
git checkout v4.0.1
git apply ../unstaged.diff
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine but it does not keep the **Untracked Files**
Any modification to get the untracked files as well.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there different ways to acheive what you want. You can stash your changes and pop them in the desired branch : `v4.0.1`.

Assuming you are on branch `v4.0`, with your unstaged changes, execute the following commands :

```
    git stash -u
    git checkout v4.0.1
    git stash pop
```

You can then stage your changes and commit them in branch `v4.0.1`.

*Note that th `-u` option is only needed if there are untracked files in your workspace.*